# Word for other side of telephone call

Tags: word-request

Say I have a table with list of telephone calls. This table contains both incoming and outgoing calls received or made by me. There is a column with number of person I called to in case of outgoing call and number of person I received call from in case of incoming call. I want to know what's most appropriate word to put in header of this column.

What's the common word for one who I call to and one whose call I receive?

Comment: Is there a description of the people you are calling or are calling you? What do you call them? Are they clients or subscribers for example... or are they a random collection of many different types of people?

Comment: @Catija They're subscribers of cell network of course. But I am subscriber as well. Nothing else is in common among them. Neither friends nor customers nor colleagues.

Comment: Well, if the only people who call you or you call are subscribers, that makes a perfectly acceptable title for the column... you being a subscriber yourself doesn't change or muddy that fact.

Comment: Besides 'other party' you could consider the not-so-common *[interlocutor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/interlocutor)*. It doesn't necessarily refer to a party of a phone call but it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single generic word you may be looking for is **Contacts**.

On the one hand, they are the **contacts** you made *going out*, and on the other hand they are the **contacts** *coming in* to you.

It can also be used for any form of contact-*ing*: emails, letters, face-to-face visits.  Usually a CRM system like Salesforce.com will break these down into narrower categories to specifically pinpoint where conversions are being generated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to go with something generic because I don't believe there's a term that can mean either at the same time.

An example would be "Other party". "Other" implies that it's not you in a way that "party" by itself does not.

If all of the people who call you or you call fit a certain description, you can also use that description as your header... so, if you work at a call center where everyone you call or who calls you is a customer, you could title the column "Customer name".

Answer (score 1):

From your perspective, the people called you would be **callers**, the people you called to would be **receivers**.

Answer (score 0):

The person who calls is referred to as the **caller**, while person who is being called is the **recipient**. These are just general terms. If you're looking for more technical terms, a caller is also called the **calling party**, the **call originator** or **A-party**, while the recipient is the **called party** or sometimes the **B-Number**/**B-party**.

In this case, the only overlap is **party**, so I would just call them the **other party**.

Comment: Right, but the OP needs a word that means both "caller" and "recipient" because they are both caller and recipient depending on the call.

Comment: I'm looking for one single word with which I can refer to both calling and called parties. _Party_?

Comment: I don't believe there's a specific term for that, so you might just go with "other party", "user", or maybe "subscriber".